# Twitter Bootstrap 3 pull-right hangs on small windows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Twitter Bootstrap 3 project I have an alert div. It has button on left and send button on right. I add pull-right to send button. Everyting works for big screens. Right side button sits well in right.
[image]

But In small windows, button hangs in the right side of the alert div, but  overflows the div. How can I extend the alert div so the right button will be inside the div ? Or any other solution that suits this condition ?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/aaVMt/4/

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="ab1">
        <div id="ac1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Text <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="">Text 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="">Text 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div style="display:inline-block;">
                <div id="a1">
                    <p>Some text some text this is my elegant text hello world this text is cool 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="aaa">
                Send
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add class `row` to the div `<div id="ac1" class='row'>`.

Here is working example : 
**http://jsfiddle.net/aaVMt/5/**

What I did is :

Replaced `<div id="ac1">` with `<div id="ac1" class='row'>`

Comment: Thank you. But that solution fixes left and right buttonsto right and left sides without margin. Right button is glued to right side..

Comment: Of course adding margin-right:10px and margin-left:10px to each buttons is an additional solution.

Comment: You are write.. .row has negative margin. I don't understand why.. Another solution would be nullifying the margin or do this : http://jsfiddle.net/aaVMt/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="ab1">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="pull-left col-xs-6 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
             <div id="ac1">
                 <div class="btn-group">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Text <span class="caret"></span>
                     </button>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                         <li><a href="#" onclick="">Text 1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" onclick="">Text 2</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>

               <div style="display:inline-block;">
                   <div id="a1">
                       <p>Some text some text this is my elegant text hello world this text is cool 1</p>
               </div>
        </div>            
         </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="aaa">
            Send
        </button>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/aaVMt/4/

Answer (score 0):

To address the actual problem that was asked (and to not cause side effects as demonstrated in the accepted answer), you should add the `clearfix` class to the div.

```
<div id="ac1" class="clearfix">
  ...
</div>
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/aaVMt/22/

An element with the clearfix class will clear all floating content before its end, ensuring that the elements inside it are properly contained. You can find out more about floats and clearing in the CSS-Tricks article [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

The accepted answer uses the `row` class, an extension of `clearfix` with additional attributes (the negative margins). You should only use `row` if you're intending to pair it with `col-*` classes for layout.